# A wired data logging brick

Tags: ev3, programming

I need a data logging brick where I can wire an input to the file name. Is this possible? and if so how would I do this?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, but I'm not sure this is the data logging brick you expected.

The File Access Block provides the option to wire the filename.  Click on the upper right corner of the block and a dropdown will appear, select "Wired".

For example:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you really need a data logging block where the file name is determined by the input, I'm afraid that this is not possible.

The normal data logging block has a constant as file name:

[image]

Maybe you can use a switch for different file names? But this can get out of hand very quickly for many different file names.

Maybe you can give us some more hints.

Comment: Oh yes, @dfrevert is right. It is possible with the normal file block. But not with the data logging block.